# Find the residues of $f(z) = \left( \frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1+z} {1+z^{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

Consider the function $$f(z) = \left( \frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^{\!\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1+z} {1+z^{2}}$$
I want to calculate the residues of $f$ in $\{+i,-i\}$.
Using the usual techniques, we have that $$\mathrm{Res}(f,i) = \left( \frac{i-1}{i+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1+i} {2i}$$Then $$\sqrt{i-1} = e^{\frac{1}{2}Log(i-1)} = e^{\frac{1}{2}(Log(\sqrt2 e^{\frac{3}{4}\pi i})} = e^{\frac{1}{2}(log\sqrt 2+ \frac{3}{4}\pi i)} = \sqrt[4]{2}e^{\frac{3}{8}\pi i}$$ $$\sqrt{i+1} = e^{\frac{1}{2}Log(i+1)} = e^{\frac{1}{2}(Log(\sqrt2 e^{\frac{1}{4}\pi i})} = e^{\frac{1}{2}(log\sqrt 2+ \frac{1}{4}\pi i)} = \sqrt[4]{2}e^{\frac{1}{8}\pi i}$$ $$\mathrm{Res}(f,i) = \frac{\sqrt[4]{2}e^{\frac{3}{8}\pi i}}{\sqrt[4]{2}e^{\frac{1}{8}\pi i}}\frac{1+i} {2i} = e^{\frac{1}{4}\pi i}\frac{1+i} {2i} = e^{\frac{1}{4}\pi i}\frac{\sqrt2 e^{\frac{1}{4}\pi i}} {2i} = \frac{\sqrt2 e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi i}} {2i} = \frac{\sqrt2 i} {2i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$ Analogously I obtain $$\mathrm{Res}(f, -i) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$ Are my method/calculations correct ?

Comment: How is the square root part of $f$ defined? As you know, there is no such thing as a continuous function $z\mapsto z^{1/2}$ defined on the complex plane.

Comment: @Did: I used the principal branch of the logarithm

Comment: Sorry? On which domain for $z$? Mapped into which domain for $(z-1)/(z+1)$?

Comment: @Did : I want to use $f$ to calculate this integral $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{(1-x^{2})}}{1+x^{2}}dx$

Comment: Hence you need to specify the domain on which you want to define a square root of $1-z^2$, not a square root of $(z-1)/(z+1)$--but this is as crucial as before to do so (that is, more seriously than by bandying phrases such that "principal branch of the logarithm").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, if $a$ is a simple pole of $f$, then 
$$
\mathrm{Res}(f,a)=\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z),
$$
and hence your answer is correct.